# SQLAlchemy Как выполнить такой запрос?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, запрос-в-запросе

Имеется:

```
With SQ AS (
SELECT theme_id,color_id FROM Table
)
SELECT *
FROM (
         SELECT *,
                (
                    SELECT count(1)
                    FROM SQ sq1
                    WHERE sq1.theme_id = sq.theme_id
                      AND sq1.color_id >= sq.color_id
                ) thres
         FROM SQ sq
     ) tbl
```

Как перенести запрос такого вида в SQLAlchemy?
Сложность в том что запрос вызывается внутри самого себя (SQ)

Comment: Так это же тривиальный `COUNT() OVER ()`.

Comment: @Akina Как я могу использовать его для получения колонки со значением текущего повторения элемента?, например, есть столбец со значениями аа аб ас аа aa ас аа, рядом с ним должен быть столбец со значениями 1 1 1 2 3 2 4

Comment: Тогда наоборот, `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY поле)`.

Comment: @Akina Это делает то что мне нужно, пойду попробую в алхимию все перенести, спасибо)